# React not immediately displaying current state

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm creating a React / .NET application that makes an API call to the OpenWeather API. The user types in their current city and presses submit to receive the temperature, location and summary of the weather. The API call and the data displays fine, and everything seems to work ok. I wanted to show the user whether it was t-shirt weather, depending on if the temperature was > or < than 18 degrees celsius. I created a "decision" state to update depending on the current temperature. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      temp: "",
      summary: "",
      city: "",
      location: "",
      decision: ""
    };
  }

  getData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("api/weather/city/" + this.state.location)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          temp: data.temp,
          summary: data.summary,
          city: data.city
        })
      );
  }

  isItSunny = async () => {
    if (Math.floor(this.state.temp) > 18.0) {
      this.setState({ decision: "Yes" });
    } else if (this.state.temp == "") {
      this.setState({ decision: "" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ decision: "No" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>Weather</h1>
          <p>Please enter your city:</p>
          <form
            onSubmit={e => {
              this.isItSunny();
              this.getData(e);
            }}
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type city here..."
              value={this.state.location}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ location: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <h4>City</h4>
          <p>{this.state.city}</p>
          <h4>Temperature</h4>
          <p> {this.state.temp}</p>
          <h4>Description</h4>
          <p> {this.state.summary}</p>
          <p>Is it T Shirt Weather: {this.state.decision}</p>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My issue is that when I click submit, the `this.state.decision` does not render. I have to click submit a second time for it to update. On the first submit, it still thinks that `this.state.decision == ""` which shouldn't be the case, it should now be a number.

Can someone please advise me as to what I can do to make the code immediately recognise the updated state of the temperature on submission of the form please? Sorry, I am new to React!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `submit` is first clicked, `this.state.temp` is always the initial value of `""`. You should *render* the `decision` instead of hold it in state because it is derived from state:

```
  render() {

    let decision = "";
    if (Math.floor(this.state.temp) > 18.0) {
      decision = "Yes";
    } else if (this.state.temp == "") {
      decision = "";
    } else {
      decision = "No";
    }     

    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>Weather</h1>
          <p>Please enter your city:</p>
          <form
            onSubmit={e => {
              this.isItSunny();
              this.getData(e);
            }}
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type city here..."
              value={this.state.location}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ location: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <h4>City</h4>
          <p>{this.state.city}</p>
          <h4>Temperature</h4>
          <p> {this.state.temp}</p>
          <h4>Description</h4>
          <p> {this.state.summary}</p>
          <p>Is it T Shirt Weather: {decision}</p>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This code can be improved but should give you the idea.  You don't need to hold `decision` in state because you can calculate it from state you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Let debug the code. You called the `this.isItSunny()` function first. So goes to the function and find the initial temp of the city is `""`. So `this.setState({decision:""})` will pause here. Then it goes to the `this.getData(e)` function and set the `temp:{value}`. After that it sets the `this.setState({decision:""})`. Here is the problem. Because it does not check the condition again. You can do the same thing just remove `this.isItSunny()` function from

```
<form
      onSubmit={e => {
      //this.isItSunny();
      this.getData(e);
   }}
>
```

Then add `this.isItSunny()` function after setting the value in the `this.getData(e)` function. Here is the code of `this.getData(e)` function:

```
async getData(e) {
    const response = await fetch("api/weather/city/" + this.state.location);
    const data= await response.json();
    await this.setState({ temp: data.temp,
          summary: data.summary,
          city: data.city });
    this.isItSunny();
}
```